# Multiple CrudPanel on a single CRUD page in laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

[image][image]In laravel-backpack i want to create custom show page which contain multiple crud page with different styles/formats:

One example : i have Show page for person model and i want to add "Add new Note" option for note model insides of person Show page.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create a new [Backpack widget](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/base-widgets#about-1) and add it to the end of the Show operation.

Alternatively, you can [create a custom Operation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operations#creating-a-custom-operation-1), and use the ShowOperation as an example.

Comment: I want to create the page with the interface which looks like the interface in attached picture

Comment: if i create custom operation, can i access more than one controller in single operation?